# Using a normal distirbution for count data

Tags: regression

I was just wondering if it is possible to use a normal mixed model for count data. Would it be better to use a Poisson regression if your response is count data?

Answer (score 2):

I won't repeat the answer, found here:

[Why is Poisson regression used for count data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3024/why-is-poisson-regression-used-for-count-data)

But in short, you should use a Poisson regression for integer data (including count data), assuming the mean and variance are equal, or you might want to look at this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution