# How do I correctly compare bacterial counts from mice with different genotypes?

Tags: anova, poisson-distribution, biostatistics, logarithm

As far as I know, CFU counts from bacterial suspensions should approximately follow a Poisson distribution. So in order to perform a One-way Anova, a mathematical transformation to achieve normality should be done. Am I correct on this? And which transformation would be ideal in this case? .

My issue is to compare means of colony forming unit counts from 3 groups of 8 mice. Each group has a different genotype. Shapiro-Wilks test for normality showed that the counts do not follow a normal distribution.

---

Thank you very much.

At least some of my counts are very large (mean counts for the three different groups are: G1: 337150; G2: 43000, G3: 16536000.  However, I am unsure wether Poisson regression may be performed on counts this large.

The variance of the samples is huge (2.28397E+10^11; 4102357143;    9.29586E*10^14). This would constitute over dispersion, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to transform count data to a true normal distribution. Counts only have integer, non-negative values, while values from a normal distribution may be any real number.

What you need to do is [Poisson regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3024/28500), as discussed also on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/142338/28500).