# What test should I use for my data?

Tags: categorical-data, spss, continuous-data

I have one categorical predictor coded as 0 or 1 for a sample of about 290.
Based on some research, I want to control for 4 covariates. One is continuous (age) and the rest are categorical (gender, ever having used certain drugs as either yes or no).

My outcome is number of violent acts - this is what I'm having trouble with. According to a professor at my university this isn't a true continuous variable as it is an interval variable. This confused me as I've used interval variables as continuous in other tests.

What type of test would I use if my outcome was continuous? Do I need to use a different one for my interval data?

I am using SPSS to analyze my data. After finding base associations (using t-tests) between my predictor and outcome and covariates and outcome, I tried to go further.
I did a univariate analysis of variance (under general linear models) with my predictor as a fixed factor. This seems logical as there's a section for covariates, but I honestly have no idea. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have counts of a type of event as your dependent variable then you should use an analysis that is designed for that type of dependent variable. [Poisson regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) is the simplest choice to start. Your predictor of main interest and the covariates would be the independent variables, similarly to the standard multiple linear regression you might perform with a truly continuous dependent variable, but they now help predict the probability of an event's occurrence.

Several Cross Validated pages explain the advantages of Poisson regression or related count-specific analyses, for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3024/28500) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/142338/28500). Unless you have so many events that your dependent variable is very close to continuous, then a multiple regression treating your dependent variable as having Poisson, overdispersed Poisson, or negative binomial characteristics would seem to make the most sense.  (These are examples of *generalized* linear models; be careful with the choice of terminology.)