# How to compare counts to find out which are significantly different

Tags: anova, count-data

I have a one way unbalanced anova say with **a** levels.

My task is to find out if we have significantly different COUNTS at the various **a** levels.

I tried this : I compute the sum of the number of cases at each level **a** say $n_i$

How do I compute if the $n_i's$ are significantly different ? I do not have a measure of the internal variation in the $n_i's$

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you should run a generalized linear model with the Poisson distribution that handles counts appropriately (and not ANOVA). See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression and here:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3024/why-is-poisson-regression-used-for-count-data/3027

Comment: Dear Stefan, Thank you for your reply. I will try to do this on my own and come back to you if I have any more queries.