# People count regression analysis

Tags: regression, poisson-regression

I have data of number of customers entering a business and number of customers leaving a business every 15 minutes.
I need to predict the number of people that will be entering and leaving the business on the next 15 and 30 minutes.
I can also  save old data for 2-3 weeks.

I want a simple model with a high success rate.
I read about linear regression and also read that this might not be the best model cause of negative values and Poisson regression might suit better.

I would be happy to read recommendations regarding my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have seasonality, or more precisely [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities), since you may have intra-daily patterns, and these may differ by the day of week.

In addition, your data are [count-data](/questions/tagged/count-data). Unless you have large numbers (rule of thumb: more than 30 in each 15 minute bucket), you should address this and not use a normal distribution approximation.

I would recommend a [Poisson regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3024/1352) with predictors accounting for the seasonalities, e.g., using harmonics or bump functions. Two weeks of historical data is very little to capture seasonalities, though, especially *differing* patterns by day of week. Try to get more data.

Be sure to use a good accuracy measure for evaluating your forecasts, e.g., the [rmse](/questions/tagged/rmse). If you use the [mae](/questions/tagged/mae), your forecasts may be biased, or you may "find" that a flat zero forecast is "best":

- [Why use a certain measure of forecast error (e.g. MAD) as opposed to another (e.g. MSE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45875/1352)
- [Why does minimizing the MAE lead to forecasting the median and not the mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/355538/1352)

Alternatively, and even better, use proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules) to assess your forecasts. I have written a little paper [(Kolassa, 2016, *IJF*)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207016000315) on this that you may find interesting.